# How to send java object as post parameter with server bean mapping

Tags: java, apache, rest

I am currently writing a client to access rest service, the server rest call accepts one parameter of type java object with @BeanParam annotated.
How do i send data from Apache HTTP client to achieve this.

Below is my server and client code

Server code

```
@Override
@POST
@Path("/generate_verify_otp/{issuername}")
@Produces("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public MultivaluedMap<String, Object> generateVerifyOTP(@BeanParam QPayOTPRequest qpayOTPRequest, @PathParam("issuername")) {

  some business logic
}
```

Client code

```
public void getOtp(HttpServletRequest request){

    QPayOTPRequest qpayOTPRequest = formatDataForOtp(request);

     StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
     JsonGenerator jgen;
    try {
        jgen = new JsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(writer);
        jgen.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());
         jgen.writeObject(qpayOTPRequest);
         jgen.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     System.out.println(writer.toString());

     String url = "sdfghjklfghjk;
     CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 
     try {
         HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity entiry = new StringEntity(writer.toString());
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(entiry);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

How to i send parameters from client so that it maps to @beanparam object.

Comment: I thought you just send it with normal query params which then get mapped using `public MyBeanParam(@QueryParam("q") String queryParam) {
        this.queryParam = queryParam;
    }`  see https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2224

Comment: Yes that's true in case of (@QueryParam, but my legacy code has (@BeanParam which takes java object as an argument.

Comment: Jersey creates the Bean based upon the queryparams - see the link I gave you